# Configuring SQL dialect to be SOQL in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, salesforce, soql

I have a project that includes SOQL statements (SalesForce query language) in the code. The code includes names of tables, such as, for example `Case` (probably one of the most important tables in SalesForce), and fields in SOQL format, such as `Case.id`.
When I run Code Inspect in the code, I get two types of problems:

1. The code inspector tells me that `case` is a reserved keyword and should be quoted
2. The inspector complains about basically all field and table names, saying it cannot resolve them.

I believe this is because I don't know how to define SOQL as my SQL dialect. How is this done?